Как отсортировать записи по нескольким критериям в MSSQL?

В программе я задаю название машины из таблицы, на выходе я должен получить заказы которые выполнялись на ней, как это реализовать?

Если под сортировкой понимается фильтрация, то указываете where field = value

@SwaD я пытался сделать вот так: Select * From dbo.orders
where id_rented_car = (select id_car from dbo.Cars) AND (select id_car from dbo.Cars) = (select model from dbo.Cars) AND (select model from dbo.Cars) Like 'Hyndai Accent', но у меня ошибка: Вложенный запрос вернул больше одного значения. Это запрещено, когда вложенный запрос следует после =, !=, <, <=, >, >= или используется в качестве выражения.

@Swad спасибо за подсказку, все получилось. Если интересно то вот так:
DECLARE id_car_hide INT;
SET  id_car_hide = (select id_car from dbo.Cars where model = 'Hyndai Accent')
Select * From dbo.orders
where id_rented_car = id_car_hide

SQL запрос легко читается, если его перевести на русский. Попробуйет прочитать и рассказать, что значит вот это AND (select id_car from dbo.Cars) = (select model from dbo.Cars) Вы слева выводите все id_car и пытаетесь их сравнить со всем model? Ну и как бы это никогда не сработает.

Select * From dbo.orders where id_rented_car = (select id_car from dbo.Cars where model = 'Hyndai Accent') - Если гарантировано возвращается 1 запись. Для множества записей будет так: Select * From dbo.orders where id_rented_car in (select id_car from dbo.Cars where model = 'Hyndai Accent')

@SwaD Спасибо за разъяснение, 2 способ для множества записей как раз и нужен был)

Выполнить выборку данных из одной таблицы по фильтру записей из другой можно следующим образом:
Если в подзапросе гарантировано возвращается 1 запись:
Select * From dbo.orders 
where id_rented_car = (
    select id_car from dbo.Cars where model = 'Hyndai Accent'
) 

Для множества записей будет так(Используется IN оператор):
Select * From dbo.orders 
where id_rented_car in (
    select id_car from dbo.Cars where model = 'Hyndai Accent'
)

Выборка без поздапросов, с использованием JOIN оператора:
Select o.* From dbo.orders o
join dbo.Cars c on c.id_car = o.id_rented_car
where c.model = 'Hyndai Accent';

